# Facebook notification not being sent

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble with facebook notifications. Although i am receiving success = 1 from facebook api, no notification is received.

Here is my debug information

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X POST \
   -d "template=This%20is%20my%20test" \
   -d "type=generic" \
   -d "ref=test" \
   -d "access_token=<access token sanitized>" \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/10154047356836239/notifications"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [],
    "user_id": null,
    "app_id": hidden
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters

  {}
- POST Parameters

  {
    "template": "This is my test",
    "type": "generic",
    "ref": "test"
  }
==== Response
  {
    "success": true,
    "__debug__": {}
  }
```

10154047356836239 is my user and i confirm its the correct one. Accessing 10154047356836239/?fields=email returns the proper email.

Edit: App notifications are turned on and app is allowed to send me notifications.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think the `href` parameter is optional ...

Comment: @CBroe it works without it but just in case i also set href=/ but same thing. I get success = true but no notification.

Comment: _“it works without it”_ - documentation says, _“This will be used to construct an absolute target URL based on your app settings. The logic is that, on web, if the setting exists for games on Facebook.com, the target URL will comprise Game App URL + href. If not, the notification will not be shown.”_ So try a proper _relative_ URL that makes a valid target, when concatenated to your app’s base URL.

Comment: @CBroe why "/" isn't a valid relative url? I don't have other urls since its a flash game.

Comment: I am not saying it wasn’t, I am saying you need to make sure it actually makes sense in combination with your app URL.

Comment: It is, since its a flash game and it has only the base url